# How find Upper Case string is not Equal lower case

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

How I find string with Upper Case is not Equal with Lower Case for example Me is not Equal with me. length of each string is random

```
string a="Me";
string b="me";
a is not equal b
```

Answer (score 0):

```
internal static bool CheckIfStringAreEqual(string s1, string s2)
{
   if (s1 == s2)//You can also use Equals() method
   {
        return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
string a = "Me";
string b = "me";


bool areEqual = YourClassName.CheckIfStringAreEqual(a,b);

Console.WriteLine(areEqual);
```

It should print False.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
==                                  Equals()
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Compares the content of strings.    Compares the content of strings.
Always compares case-sensitive.     Compares case-sensitive or insensitive, 
                                    culture specific or invariant culture 
                                    strings using StringComparison enum.
Compares null values also.          Throws NullReferenceException if string 
                                    is null.
Cannot be overloaded.               Can be overloaded to customize it.
```

From this [link](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/compare-strings-in-csharp#:%7E:text=The%20%3D%3D%20operator%20always%20compares%20strings%20case%2Dsensitive.&text=Use%20the%20Equals()%20method,case%2Dinsensitive%20using%20StringComparison%20parameter.)

You should search in the internet first. Jostojoo!!